# PHP - Convert a string with dashes while removing first word

Tags: php

```
$title = '228-example-of-the-title'
```

I need to convert the string to:

Example Of The Title

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one-liner,

```
$title = '228-example-of-the-title';
ucwords(implode(' ', array_slice(explode('-', $title), 1)));
```

- This splits the string on dashes (`explode(token, input)`),
- minus the first element (`array_slice(array, offset)`)
- joins the resulting set back up with spaces (`implode(glue, array)`),
- and finally capitalises each word (thanks [salathe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113938/salathe)).

Comment: There's no real need to create an array for that when we have `ucwords()`.

Comment: Aha, that makes it simpler :) I always forget about that.

Comment: and thinking properly, you could just apply ucwords to the substr+strpos answers and you'd have no array nonsense at all..

Answer (score 2):

```
$title = '228-example-of-the-title'
$start_pos = strpos($title, '-');
$friendly_title = str_replace('-', ' ', substr($title, $start_pos + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [explode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the "-" and put the string in an array

```
$title_array = explode("-",$title);
$new_string = "";

for($i=1; $i<count($title_array); $i++)
{
$new_string .= $title_array[$i]." ";
}

echo $new_string;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the following code

```
$title = '228-example-of-the-title';

$parts = explode('-',$title);
array_shift($parts);
$title = implode(' ',$parts);
```

functions used: [explode](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) [implode](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [array_shift](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Comment: exactly, lol i typed out almost the exact same thing before you posted, lol

Answer (score 1):

```
$pieces = explode("-", $title);
$result = "";
for ($i = 1; $i < count(pieces); $i++) {
    $result = $result . ucFirst($pieces[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$toArray = explode("-",$title);
$cleanArray = array_shift($toArray);
$finalString = implode(' ' , $cleanArray);
// echo ucwords($finalStirng);
```